# Why does django-channels not connect to secure Websockets wss?

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, asgi

Lately I have been developing an app called(DBSF - don't be a sh***y friend), which functions a little bit like facebook, but it reminds you to interact with your friends once in a while.
I've encountered a bug that I have been unable to fix for a long time.

The app works fine on my local machine but I run into one bug when I try to deploy the app to heroku.

The issue is about the chat function between users which uses Websockets and Django-channels.
It is caused by heroku requiring https, therefore the websockets have to be secure as well (wss:// instead of ws://).

So I did that, I created a secure webSocket with a url that starts with wss://

And here is where the bug happens: the connection never gets established for some reason the the asgi.py file, or the routing.py file can't connect the websocket to the correct consumer in consumers.py

**Here's how I tried to fix the bug:**

1. in asgi.py I changed http to https, or websocket to one of these(websockets, ws wss)
2. changed security settings in settings.py
3. tried different combinations of the websocket url
4. running it with daphne instead of Django's development server

None of these changed the bug or even the error messages.

The error message always complains that the socket is still connecting or already closing or in closing state

Here's some code

on the browser (to recreate the bug on my local machine i just hard code 'wss'):

```js
var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
      const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        ws_scheme
        + '://'
        + window.location.host
        + '/ws/chat/'
        + friendship_id
        + '/'
      );
```

here's asgi.py

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DBSF.settings")

import django
django.setup()

from django.core.management import call_command


from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import social.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DBSF.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            social.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

here's routing.py

```py
from django.urls import re_path, path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<friendship_id>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
    
]
```

here's consumers.py

```py
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from .models import Message, Friendship, User
import datetime

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
   
    def connect(self):
        print('fuuuuuuuu')
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['friendship_id']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        sender = text_data_json['sender']
        receiver = text_data_json['receiver']
        friendship_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['friendship_id']
        message_to_save = Message(conversation=Friendship.objects.get(id=friendship_id), sender=User.objects.get(username=sender), receiver=User.objects.get(username=receiver), text=message, date_sent=datetime.datetime.now())
        message_to_save.save()

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message,
                'sender': sender,
                'receiver': receiver,
                'id': message_to_save.id
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        sender = event['sender']
        receiver = event['receiver']
        id = event['id']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'sender': sender,
            'receiver': receiver,
            'id': id,
        }))
```

Here is settings.py:

```py
"""
Django settings for DBSF project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import django_heroku
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'social.User'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['desolate-lowlands-74512.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 3600
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'social',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DBSF.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DBSF.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'DBSF.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('https://desolate-lowlands-74512.herokuapp.com/', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        'TIME_ZONE': 'EST'
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'EST'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL= "/media/"
```

Here is the error message:

```
layout.js:108 WebSocket connection to 'wss://desolate-lowlands-74512.herokuapp.com/ws/chat/19/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Here is the full project:
https://github.com/fabianomobono/DBSF

And here is the app on heroku:
https://desolate-lowlands-74512.herokuapp.com/

Basically the one of the files asgi.py , routing.py or consumers.py can't work with wss WebSockets.

The app works when I use a normal webSocket(ws) on my local machine.

I really thought this would be an easy issue to fix but I have been trying for weeks now.

Is this a small bug or is the way I am trying to approach this completely wrong?

Could this be a bug of django-channels??

Please let me know if you'd be able to help me with this or if you could point me in the direction of someone who faced this problem before.

Please let me know if I explained this bug well enough or if it is not clear what I am asking.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You might try running it on ""0.0.0.0" instead of "127.0.0.1" I had a problem using flask socket io https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920267/how-to-setup-flask-socketio-in-a-docker-container Just a thing to try

Comment: you mean with the runserver command?
What's the command python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0 does not seet to work

Comment: In allowed hosts you have "127.0.0.1" maybe try to replace with "0.0.0.0"

Comment: hmmm no luck. added it to allowed host but the python manage.py runsenserver still connects to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: and  when I run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 I get an error...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.  I want the frontend to open a wss connection to the backend but it never gets established.  This is my asgi.  It works fine for ws connections but I'm not sure what needs to be changed so that the backend can support wss connections.


application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": URLRouter([path('ws/notifications/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi())]),
    }
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to connect on localhost with some changes. Before that changes it does not work even for ws:// protocol. So my changes:

1. Are you sure that you setup correct redis? for testing you can try

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    },
}
```

2. in code on github, you have error in route, it was:

```
   re_path(r'wss/chat/(?P<friendship_id>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

but it should be

```
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<friendship_id>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

according to your javascript code.

Good luck, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Anton! This works great for testing and for Heroku, but I read on the channels documentation not to use InMemoryChannelLayer for production. What should I use for production???

Comment: you need to enable redis for heroku and get connecting string for it and put it in the settings.py

Comment: is this what you mean?                 



`
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis://:p83d12345c9a9b171d9c0b954aa60a2b15bef62e6ae30e06877a1e9bc8794b13@ec2-50-16-233-129.compute-1.amazonaws.com:27039", 27039)],
        },
    },
}
`  


                             
  
I found these credentials on in my Add-ons on in the Heroku Redis Add-on settings folder
Something is still wrong here, because it still does not connect...

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out!

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": *** the heroku-redis URI as it is with the port number at the end
        },
    },
}

and no port as second argument => no second argument at all

I hope this will save someone a lot of time!

Thank you Anton! You are a SuperHero...I definitely owe you a beer if we ever meet in real life

Comment: thank you) maybe someday will drink beer, good luck)

Comment: @FabianOmobono, I'm still getting the 404 error, but your answer gives me hope I'm close. Can you describe more how you set up CHANNEL_LAYERS? Here's how I've got it: CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_TLS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this too. I had to change REDIS_TLS_URL to REDIS_URL and I had to fix my Procfile to use daphne.